# Laravel 5.4 get api authenticated user instance

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have a question. In laravel 5.4, I assgin `auth:api` middleware to my route, and I want to get user instance. I found both way `$user = Auth::user()` and `$user = Auth::guard('api')->user()` get the same user. But in my `auth.php` file the dafault guard is `web` not `api`. So both way are right or it is just a coincidence? Thanks.